Make build fail due to typedef redefinition with different types

I was trying build this example https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/examples/c 
I was trying build it using make and i am facing this error
error: typedef redefinition with different types ('__uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') vs 'unsigned long')
   60 | typedef __uint64_t uint64_t ;
note: previous definition is here
   34 | typedef unsigned long int uint64_t;

error: typedef redefinition with different types ('__uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') vs 'unsigned long')
   60 | typedef __uint64_t uint64_t ;
note: previous definition is here
   34 | typedef unsigned long int uint64_t;

If someone has any solution please let me know

It works on my side, have you installed the Solana tool suite? If you haven't run cargo build-sbf, the compiler might not actually be available unfortunately.
There's a helper script for installing the C compiler at https://github.com/joncinque/solana-program-rosetta/blob/main/install-solana-c.sh -- feel free to follow those steps!
